# Share a photograph to a website from the "share with" button

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, raspberry-pi, photo-gallery

I am working on a school project and there is something we would like to do but we don't know how to.

First, let me explain the project.

This is a system, composed of a Raspberry, you can connect to this rasp by Wi-Fi and go to a website by typing a specefic IP in the url bar of the native browser of your phone, once you are on the website, you can upload a photograph on the raspberry, which is connected to a projector, and will make a slide of all pictures uploaded by peoples.

The problem is that this is very annoying to use a browser, type the IP and click on a button to upload a photo, we want that anyone can upload a picture to our site by going on the native Gallery app of their phone, choose a picture and click on "Share with" then choose an option that upload the picture to our site. We don't know if this is possible but if you have any idea of how we can do it, would be nice to tell us. You have to know that we can't make an app for the phone and it would be very nice if it can works on iOs, Android and Windows Phone.

I searched "Sharing a picture on phone with WI-FI" but I found nothing.